# Не получается сформировать правильный API запрос к AllPositions

Tags: python, post, api

Столкнулась с проблемой получения данных с сайта allpositions.ru.
Поскольку до этого формировала только get запросы, не до конца понимаю технику. В документации к API сайта (http://allpositions.ru/help/api/) сказано, что тело документа должно находиться в post_data в utf-8, поэтому сделала вывод о post запросе. Также речь идет о xml-rpc интерфейсе, неизвестно для меня как влияющем на форму запроса. На основании уже имеющихся примеров других участников и малого собственного опыта было написано следующее:

```
import requests
adr = 'http://allpositions.ru/api/'
api_key = '3057dbbb593948f9631d533f0ad472af'

xml_call = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<methodCall>\n<methodName>get_report</methodName>\n \
    <params>\n<param>\n<value><int>" +str(ipr)+ "</int></value>\n</param>\n<param>\n<value><string>\n</string></value>\n \
    </param>\n<param>\n<value><string></string></value>\n</param>\n<param>\n<value><int></int></value>\n \
    </param>\n<param>\n<value><int>1</int></value>\n</param>\n</params>\n</methodCall>"

optAdvancedArgs = {
    'headers': {'Cookie': 'api_key=' + api_key + ';'},
    'contentType': 'application/xml',
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': xml_call
    }
r = requests.post(url = adr, data = optAdvancedArgs) 
r.text
```

В ответ сервер дает мне только

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<methodResponse>\n<fault>\n\t<value>\n\t\t<struct>\n\t\t\t<member>\n\t\t\t\t<name>faultCode</name>\n\t\t\t\t<value><int>105</int></value>\n\t\t\t</member>\n\t\t\t<member>\n\t\t\t\t<name>faultString</name>\n\t\t\t\t<value><string>XML error: Invalid document end at line 1</string></value>\n\t\t\t</member>\n\t\t</struct>\n\t</value>\n</fault>\n</methodResponse>'
```

Скорее всего я не даю достаточно данных или формирую неправильно запрос из-за недостатка знаний и опыта. Поэтому благодарна за любую помощь и разъяснение ошибок.

Comment: Тут не надо гадать, надо только перевести ошибку - `XML error: Invalid document end at line 1`.. Вы не правильно xml формируете, возможно где-то синтаксическая ошибка есть.. Уберите все переносы `\n` и что это за слэш в конце каждой строки?

Comment: faultCode 105 что означает

Comment: @sterx `XML error: Invalid document end at line 1`

Comment: Еще немного изменив код `from xmlrpc.client import ServerProxy
def get_connection(api_key):
    return ServerProxy('https://%s:@allpositions.ru/api' % api_key)
partner_key = '3057***48f9631d533f0***472af'
partner_api = get_connection(partner_key)
result = server.get_projects()
print(result)` пришла к ошибке `Fault: <Fault 101: 'Bad API key'>` что странно, учитывая, что этот же пароль работает в уже работающем скрипте

Comment: Все решилось после добавления API key в куки, как в этом вопросе https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7164679/how-to-send-cookies-in-a-post-request-with-the-python-requests-library

Answer (score 0):

```py
import ssl
import xmlrpc

class CookiesTransport(xmlrpc.client.SafeTransport):
    def __init__(self, context=None):
       super().__init__(context=context)
       self._cookies = ["%s=%s" % ('api_key','')]

    def send_headers(self, connection, headers):
       if self._cookies:
          connection.putheader("Cookie", "; ".join(self._cookies))
       super().send_headers(connection, headers)

transport = CookiesTransport(context=ssl._create_unverified_context())
server = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('https://allpositions.ru/api', transport=transport)
```